# Enter Value as hh:ss:mm and show it correctly

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I´m having a Excel Sheet in which I have multiple rows of raw data in the hh:mm:ss format, now I would like to get these into a SP list.

The problem is if I would insert it as a number, what I need since I want to use formation on it and compare them- it getting changed to 1,00380787 is there a way to get this shown in hh:mm:ss again?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new calculated column and use the following formula to convert the time value to a normal time:

```
=TEXT(Your time value column,"hh:mm:ss")
```